# IE9 Gives Page Expired error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer-9

IE9 gives webpage expired error suddenly on any process of my page. 
Any action I do like edit, add or delete.. after some operations .. page suddenly says expired message in IE9 only.

Our website developed in ASP.Net VB version.
Please help..

Comment: This is not enough information to post solutions to your problem. Would be interesting to know the exact sequence of actions. For instance, are you using the 'back' button, do you submit forms, is there a proxy or caching service between browser and server, etc. From your question I'd guess it has something to do with either forms being re-submitted, or in improper use of headers which affect the caching algorithm in IE9.

Comment: Thank you Bernhard. I am getting this error "Webpage has expired" when submitting page. I am not getting this error everytime. I am getting this error some times, when doing same operations many time. Like I have gridview and removing items from grid and doing same operating frequently. Its working fine, however sometimes I am getting this error. Hope you will understand the issue which I am facing.

Answer (score 1):

After doing search on google and making some effort on this, I have resolved the issue. To resolve this issue I have used following lines of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when you're using a HTTP POST to send data to the server (e.g. ASP.NET PostBack technology) and then using window.history.go or similar to navigate backward in the travellog. Because IE isn't permitted to retransmit a post without user permission, you get this warning. You can often avoid this problem by ensuring that your HTTP Response pages are cacheable and do not contain any "no-cache" or "must-revalidate" directives.

Comment: Hi EricLaw, Thank you for your response. We have tried to resolve the issue by making the changes which you have suggest. However still we are getting same error. FYI we are getting foll0wing error in ie developer toolbar: HTML0: Parser Terminated Early around 
<FORM id=Default encType=multipart/form-data method=post name=Default action=basket.aspx oldOnSubmit="null">